# Using ng-disabled on a group of inputs based on one value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm currently using one check box to toggle the disabled attribute on 8 form elements. I've used the [ngDisabled Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) on each element. I'm searching for a way that I wouldn't have to put the directive on each of the 8 elements. Is this possible?

**Checkbox Toggle**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="aircraftOnGround" />
```

**Current working Disabled directive being used on each form element**

```
ng-disabled="aircraftOnGround"
```

**Codepen here:** 
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/codekhalifah/pen/bVoexV?editors=101)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a fieldset to disable every field inside it.

```js
var $scope = {};

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.aircraftOnGround = 'true';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <form ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <fieldset ng-disabled='aircraftOnGround'> <!-- USE NG_DISABLE HERE -->
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <b>aircraftOnGround:</b> <button type="button" ng-click="aircraftOnGround = !aircraftOnGround"><span ng-bind="aircraftOnGround"></span></button>
  </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a collection of DOM elements using a watcher in your controller.

```
myapp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $element){
  $scope.aircraftOnGround = false;
  $scope.name = "abdullah";
  $scope.$watch('aircraftOnGround',function(value) {
     $element.find('.form-control').prop('disabled',value);
  });
});
```

> Note: I'm using jQuery in the example.